# Jquery caroufredsel script error 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, caroufredsel

Working on a [carousel lightbox tooltip](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/carousel-lightbox-tooltip.php) demo and as far I can see in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s39Kd/) created, the 'carouFredSel-script' isn't loaded. Error message in firebug:

```
$("#foo").carouFredSel is not a function
```

I don't see the problem. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were loading jQuery twice and you were loading the carusel in the wrong place i think http://jsfiddle.net/s39Kd/4/

Comment: @ Nicola Peluchetti Tnx! Can you tell me if the carousel script [here](http://members.chello.nl/j.bemmel2/carousel/) is in the wrong place too? I tried different order of scripts, but without succes.

Comment: @Martijn. no it seems ok, on firefox the carousel is running

Comment: @ Nicola Peluchetti Great! Could you perhaps give brief advise on my open [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9681736/1137086) here at stackoverflow on how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You loaded `http://members.chello.nl/j.bemmel2/carousel/assets/js/tooltip/jquery.js` after `jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js` was loaded, which creates a fresh jQuery object again under `window` global object, and removed the one with caroured support.

Remove `http://members.chello.nl/j.bemmel2/carousel/assets/js/tooltip/jquery.js` should work.

Comment: In my case, I have two versions of Jquery: `1.10.1` and `1.11.1`, I remove `1.10.1` and it worked. Kudos, otakustay!