# Using this web template in rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to get this free css/html/javascript template to work in rails. If you download it from [here](https://chocotemplates.com/demo/?template=curve), you can see it is an index, a single css file and two javascripts.

I placed the home.html markup in /app/view/layouts/application.html.erb, and the css in assets/stylesheets/application.css, images to assets/images/ and the two javascripts in assets/javascripts/.

I added `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css jquery-1.8.0.min.js jquery.flexslider-min.js function.js )` to config/initializers/assets.rb.

I ran `rake assets:precompile` just to be safe (if that makes any difference).

However, the template isn't rendering properly and it seems I'm getting errors in the dev console related to the javascript. However... I would have thought the top part, including the navigation section would be loaded correctly, since the hovers and other styling should be handled by the CSS.

[image]

**UPDATE**

So I added the correct script tags (I guess I assumed if it was in that folder I could also call it using raw html). The errors resolved, but I am getting an error related to 'carouFredSel is not a function'. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717447/jquery-caroufredsel-script-error-is-not-a-function) references the order of the scripts, but mine are in the same as the source. I have seen a library similar to this name, but it is not included in this template (as you can see from the source). Here is the current output:

[image]

Here is the html head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'flexslider', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag('jquery-1.8.0.min') %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag('jquery.flexslider-min') %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag('functions') %>
</head>
```

Comment: well you can't modify the html, because then the css will not target the same element structure as before. If you change the html, be sure to change the css structure too, or add the new css code similar or identical to what you initially have.

Comment: I'm not changing the element names, just trying to pick out what I need along with the css... I am under the impression I do not need the js for the navigation bar and most of the rest of the page. To make things simple, I am just keeping the entire home.html and css and putting it directly in an app.

Comment: Ok, so you have the html, but how about the css for the navigation?

Comment: As I see above you only have the html, with no css rendering whatsoever

Comment: Yes, I have the CSS as I mentioned above, I copied it in whole into my app. I know the css is getting recognized because I can change certain things and it takes affect. It's just really strange for this template I cannot get it to work, it's like I'm missing some very small important detail.

Comment: Obviously without the JS I don't expect the slider to work on the main page, but that is not a problem.

Comment: the way you posted the picture above, I can see that the css is not working, that is the basic browser rendering

Comment: I just rewrote this question, so the above comments can probably be deleted. Also, I renamed references to js/jquery...min.js to just jquery...min.js.

Comment: on my localhost, I see that not the index, but the home.html is the file that contains the template.

Comment: the errors in the console tell you that the path of the scripts are incorrect

Comment: the paths show that the files are where your "index" is and not where you specified in the description, please double check

Comment: Well I figured this was a 'rails thing'. It would find the javascripts in the correct folder and make them available. Where should I be calling them from in the html? i.e. `change src="jquery-1.8.0.min.js"` to `src="?????/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"`.

Comment: can u paste a picture of your document structure?

Comment: Of the whole rails app? It's just a standard rails 5 setup, with the adjustments for html, images and javascripts list above. When I rewrote the question I added rails tags because I think this is likely something to do with rails asset loading.

Comment: I meant the document structure, to see how you set up your files, you can try to put the whole path of the scripts, sometimes on the localhost this issue arises

Answer (score 0):

In `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`, make sure to remove `//= require jquery-ujs` or anything that might mess with your scripts.

Comment: There is only `//= require rails-ujs` and some others. But not `jquery-ujs`. Tried removing `rails-ujs` but got the same error. Also added the html head to the original question if it helps.

Comment: btw: the CSS from `style.css` in the source is in `application.css` and I also included the `flexslider.css` into `assets/stylesheets`.

Comment: @user58446 Would you be willing to upload your code to a repo? I'd be glad to help, the cause of the issue might be coming from somewhere else

Comment: actually got locked out of my github account recently. i can see about setting another one up in the meantime. however, i'm curious if you are able to just throw the css, images, js and html in to a regular `rails new app` and see if it works according to what i said i did in the original question. i actually tried this with another template a while ago and had similar issues where elements didn't render correctly. for instance, i'm not even sure where the navigation button gradient is coming from, if there is an image for it, i don't see it (or my eyes are off because the gradient is light).